# ExtJS 4 waiting for an AJAX request's results without using callback

Tags: javascript, ajax, extjs, callback

I am in a bit of a situation here and I need help. Here's an example of my code:

```
fn: function () {
    var test = this.ajaxFunction();
    alert(test);
}

ajaxFunction : function () {
    Ext.Ajax.request ({
        url: 'MyServlet',
        params: ...,
        success: function (response) {
            response = Ext.decode(response.responseText);
            return response.myVar;
        }
    });
}
```

Obviously alert will give me an undefined result instead of the myVar value. How do I fix this? I know that AJAX in Ext is supported asynchronously and wherever I search everyone tells me to put my post-Ajax logic in the callback. However as you can see here that is not possible. I need BOTH functions fn and ajaxFunction. ajaxFunction gets called by many different functions so it needs to be separate.

I have tried the "async" configuration but it doesn't seem to work. I think they have removed it (in ExtJS 4.2.1 at least).

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could pass a callback function to `ajaxFunction`:

```
fn: function () {
    this.ajaxFunction(function(response) {
        alert(response);
    });
}

ajaxFunction : function (callback) {
    Ext.Ajax.request ({
        url: 'MyServlet',
        params: ...,
        success: callback
    });
}
```

This way you could reuse `ajaxFunction`, just pass a different callback each time.

Comment: @SunnyRGupta true, it wouldn't, just overlooked it when editing OP's code. Removed it now.

Comment: Well this method was suggested by a coworker and I have made it work somewhat but seems weird to me. I am generally new to AJAX as a concept and my procedural programming way of thinking is getting confused. Generally the way things go is: Get data (through ajax or any other way) THEN work on that data. However with Async AJAX you can't just consider ajax as a function call. That's what bothers me and that's what I'm trying to achieve. Make a function call that sends an ajax request and have the program continue only after we get the data we want back.